# Accessibility issue on Mat-chip-list- aria attributes does not match their roles

Tags: angular, angular-material, wai-aria, mat-chip, aria-role

For mat-chip-list as per the document the aria-role for chiplist as listbox with each chip has option as role,even I gave those two role as mentioned in the below code,

```
<mat-chip-list #chipList role="listbox" aria-label="filtervalues">
    <span *ngFor="let x of values">
      <span *ngFor="let y of x.items">
        <mat-chip role="option">y</mat-chip>
      </span>
    </span>
</mat-chip-list>
```

unable to attain 100% accessibility,shows "aria attributes does not match their roles".How to overcome this error?

Comment: Which tool are you using? Automatic accessibility testing has its limits. Even with 100% you will still have accessibility issues, and not every error such tool produces is really an error. There always is some interpretation and manual audit necessary.
Still, I would guess that  your `<span>` elements are interferring. Why are you wrapping each option in a span instead of using the ngFor directoy on the option? `<ng-container>` lets you loop stuff without creating additional elements.